# How to enable auto reply in Gmail

Tags: gmail

I would like to share the content of my blog to know the opinion of viewers.

Do you know how to enable auto-reply in Gmail for vacation?

Answer (score 1):

From [Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/25922?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en):

> **Set up your vacation reply**
>
> 1. On your computer, open Gmail.
> 2. In the top right, click Settings (gear icon) and then **Settings**.
> 3. Scroll down to the "Vacation responder" section.
> 4. Select **Vacation responder on**.
> 5. Fill in the date range, subject, and message.
> 6. Under your message, check the box if you only want your contacts to see your vacation reply.
> 7. At the bottom of the page, click **Save Changes**.